# Not equal height of each div's element

Tags: html, css, block, footer

I'm doing a footer that is separated to 3 blocks.
But they haven't equal height, and so border-right line's height isn't equal too.

screen: [Not equal height of elements](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BIHRK.png)

What to do with it? What is wrong with it?
My way to handle this problem (3 blocks of content centered in one footer block) is bad?

Code:

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<style>
#footer {
    height: auto;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #55585d;
    margin-top: 30px;
    display: table;
}
#blocks {
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    width: 1120px;
}
.f-block {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    width: 373px;
    float: left;
    padding: 30px;
    text-align: center;
    border-right: 1px solid #000000;
}
</style>
<footer>
    <div id="footer">
        <div id="blocks">
            <nav>
                <div class="f-block">
                    asdasdaasdfghfghfghfghfghfghfghf
                </div>
            </nav>
            <div class="f-block">asdasdaaaaaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaaaasada
            </div>
            <div class="f-block">asdasdasd aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaa aaaaaaaa
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</footer>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: It seems that the one that gives you trouble is the `<div>` inside your `<nav>` element. Have you specified the `<nav>` style? Like giving it auto height?

Comment: Nav is only semantic element, without any properties and affect on code. Or am I wrong?

Comment: It does affect. Every HTML element has its style, and if you don't specify it strange things happen. Either give it a proper style, remove it or use something else

Comment: How does <nav> affect all this things? What styles have <nav> ?

Comment: You can Right Click -> Inspect Element on your webpage to see its style an structure

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove the float left, add `display: table-cell;` on child f-block so they have the same height (highest one decide all other cells height).

Also remove the `<nav></nav>` or just do `<nav class="f-block"><div></div></nav>`

Use `.f-block:nth-of-type(1)` to select the 1st `f-block` add `border-left`

```
.f-block:nth-of-type(1) {
  border-left: 1px solid #000000;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
</head>

<body>
  <style>
    #footer {
      height: auto;
      width: 100%;
      background-color: #55585d;
      margin-top: 30px;
      display: table;
      text-align: center;
    }
    
    #blocks {
      margin-left: auto;
      margin-right: auto;
      width: 1120px;
    }
    
    .f-block:nth-of-type(1) {
      border-left: 1px solid #000000;
    }
    
    .f-block {
      box-sizing: border-box;
      width: 373px;
      padding: 30px;
      text-align: center;
      border-right: 1px solid #000000;
      display: table-cell;
    }
  </style>
  <footer>
    <div id="footer">
      <div id="blocks">
        <div class="f-block">
          asdasdaasdfghfghfghfghfghfghfghf
        </div>
        <div class="f-block">asdasdaaaaaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaaaasada
        </div>
        <div class="f-block">asdasdasd aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaa aaaaaaaa
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </footer>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: There is problem. Blocks are not centered. They align to left

Comment: Why semantic <nav> is really a problem here. I need it for semantic structure of the website :/. It has to be here ehhhh

Comment: @AdriannoBarello then you have to dynamically add class to nav like `<nav class="f-block"><div></div></nav>`. Since nav have a default css `display: block`

Comment: Can't I do something like 
nav {
display: inherit;
}
Or something? To just remove nav default bad affect on this? Without adding class to nav?

Comment: Can I do this other way than assigning class to <nav>?

Comment: @AdriannoBarello From what I know, I never wrap item like that, you can wrap stuff inside, or add class to the item like `active` etc, so you can target it, really no need to wrap a `nav`

Comment: @AdriannoBarello as far as I know it is difficult

Answer (score 1):

`footer` and `#footer` seem redundant, so I combined those. And `.f-block` should be on your `nav` since it's adjacent to the other `.f-block`s. And adding `display: flex` to the parent will cause them to stretch their height to match their siblings.

```css
#footer {
  height: auto;
  width: 100%;
  margin-top: 30px;
  background-color: #55585d;
}

#blocks {
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  width: 1120px;
  display: table;
  
}

.f-block, nav {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: 373px;
  padding: 30px;
  text-align: center;
  border-right: 1px solid #000000;
  display: table-cell;
}
```

```html
<footer id="footer">
    <div id="blocks">
      <nav>
        <div>
          asdasdaasdfghfghfghfghfghfghfghf
        </div>
      </nav>
      <div class="f-block">asdasdaaaaaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaaaasada
      </div>
      <div class="f-block">asdasdasd aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaa aaaaaaaa
      </div>
    </div>
</footer>
```

Comment: I don't want to use flex. it is not widely supported. It is not solution for me. :/

Comment: Then 1) put that in your post, 2) it is widely supported and has > 97% browser support in the real world (http://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox), 3) use `display: table; display: table-cell;` instead - updated my answer.

Comment: IE 8 doesn't support flex

Comment: @AdriannoBarello 0.34% of people on the internet use IE8 http://caniuse.com/usage-table it may be a requirement for you, but to say flex isn't widely supported is incorrect.

Comment: @AdriannoBarello be more specific. What doesn't work exactly? Looks like it works for me - http://i.imgur.com/bnxYdwE.png if it isn't working for you, please clarify what you mean.

Comment: @MichaelCoker if you scroll right on the Snippet it seems to me that the background is not displaying OK

Comment: @AdriannoBarello Please do add those details to your post so people can give you the answer you need

Comment: So sorry, I should check this wrongly. I apologize. :)

Comment: @AdriannoBarello no worries, but now I'm confused. Is it working? If not please describe what isn't working.

Comment: @AdriannoBarello awesome :)

Comment: Why semantic <nav> is really a problem here. I need it for semantic structure of the website :/. It has to be here ehhhh

Comment: @AdriannoBarello what do you mean? I left `nav` in there

Comment: @AdriannoBarello oh you unselected my answer as the solution? Do you think I removed `nav`? The person you selected as having the solution removed `nav`. What's wrong with my answer?

Comment: It's okay. I just can't select two answers as the solution. I just think the other I checked is better. That's just it. Your answer is good too <3

Comment: @ AdriannoBarello  Why are you asking me "Why semantic <nav> is really a problem here."?

Comment: Because I am looking for answer :).

Comment: Your answer. That is why here

Comment: @AdriannoBarello it's not a problem. Why would it be? I didn't say it was.

Comment: But you changed this (added class to nav).

Comment: So I assume it is problem to leave this without class, RAW.

Comment: @AdriannoBarello you don't necessarily need to add a class, but you need to style it somehow. Updated my answer with a way you don't have to add a class to `nav`

Answer (score 0):

Get rid of the `<nav></nav>` wrapping the first element and add `display: flex` to `#blocks`. This will make its direct children fill all vertical space.

Example: [JSBin](https://jsbin.com/jawilejega/1/edit?html,css,js,output)

Comment: I don't want to use flex. it is not widely supported. It is not solution for me.

Comment: Then all the alternatives will be very punishing, such a dealing with a mix of `position: relative/absolute` or fixed heights. Flexbox is almost unanimously supported https://caniuse.com/#search=flex, used in the vast majority of high-profile websites, and there's even a JS polyfill in you want to support your grandma's IE8 https://github.com/jonathantneal/flexibility

Answer (score 0):

Just add `max-height` or `min-height` to the footer blocks:

```css
#footer {
    height: auto;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #55585d;
    margin-top: 30px;
    display: table;
}
#blocks {
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    width: 1120px;
}
.f-block {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    width: 373px;
    float: left;
    padding: 30px;
    text-align: center;
    border-right: 1px solid #000000;
    min-height: 96px;
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<footer>
    <div id="footer">
        <div id="blocks">
            <nav>
                <div class="f-block">
                    asdasdaasdfghfghfghfghfghfghfghf
                </div>
            </nav>
            <div class="f-block">asdasdaaaaaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaaaasada
            </div>
            <div class="f-block">asdasdasd aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaa aaaaaaaa
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</footer>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: It is bad. It makes another problem - text can go over div

Comment: @AdriannoBarello what about min-height.

Comment: or you can use javascript to calculate the height dynamically.

Comment: JS is not a solution. It is a CSS problem, need way here to solve it

Answer (score 0):

Issue here is content of the div. white-space is not handled properly. change it to something else.

```
<footer>
    <div id="footer">
        <div id="blocks">
            <nav>
                <div class="f-block">asdasdasd aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaa aaaaaaaa
                </div>
            </nav>
            <div class="f-block">asdasdaaaaaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaaaasada
            </div>
            <div class="f-block">asdasdasd aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaa aaaaaaaa
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</footer>
```